# How do nonblocking Python Sockets receive input?

Tags: python, sockets

If I have this code relating to an unblocking socket called `sock`

```
recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print('closing connection to', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
```

What exactly happens? How is the statement `recv_data = sock.recv(1024)` differ from blocking and nonblocking? If the program doesn't wait for that statement to complete, how does `recv_data` ever have value?

***Edit:***
Full server code:

```
import selectors
import socket
import types

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 65432

def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('accepted conneciton from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b'', outb=b'')
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)

def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print('closing connection to', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print('echoing', repr(data.outb), 'to', data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen()
print('listening on', (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    for key, mask in events:
        if key.data is None:
            # From the listening socket
            accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
        else:
            # Client Socket
            service_connection(key, mask)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sock` is non-blocking, it will raise `BlockingIOError` if it would block otherwise.  Is there a `try`/`except` not shown around the code?  Another option is `select.select` is used to make sure there is data read to receive before calling `recv`.

Example assuming appropriate server:

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> s=socket()
>>> s.connect(('localhost',5000))
>>> s.setblocking(0)
>>> s.recv(1024)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

**Edit:**

With the additional code, `recv` is only called when `sel.select` reports an `EVENT_READ` (data ready to read) so `recv` should not block.  It will either return data or an empty string.  The latter indicates the socket was closed.

Comment: "If it would block otherwise". What are the cases when it would block? If there is nothing to receive? If so, when would the ```else:``` condition fire if it would throw an error?

There is a ```try```/```except``` in the code. I will add the full code for context. Select is actually being used here as well.

Comment: @frownyface a socket would block when there is no data to be read in the buffer, but the connection has not closed.

Comment: @frownyface I've edited my answer based on your additional code.  There is no try/except in the code you added, but in normal conditions `recv` is only called when it is already known it won't block.

Comment: @MarkTolonen got it, yeah I realized the try/except block you asked for was to check for the error you mentioned. So now I have a new question. Does setting any of the sockets in this code to nonblocking make a difference? Since we are using select, aren't we blocking until there is input to be ready anyways?

Comment: @frownyface In normal conditions yes.  But if you have a bug or some other problem occurs, it is still possible to block, so non-blocking can raise an exception in that case instead of hanging on the call.